# Почему там сильно тормозит jquery скрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window.onload = function () {
var ar_mft_block = [],
    _inp = document.getElementsByClassName('auto-complete-prop-mft')[0].getElementsByTagName('input'),
    _block = document.getElementsByClassName('auto-complete-prop-mft-block')[0];

for(var i = 0; i < _block.childNodes.length; i++) {
    _block.childNodes[i].onclick = function () {
        for(var j = 0; j < _inp.length; j++)
            if(_inp[j].type == 'text') {
                _inp[j].value = this.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
                _inp[j].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 
                        this.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
                _block.style.display = 'none';
                break;
            }
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < _inp.length; i++) {
    if(_inp[i].type == 'text') {

        _inp[i].onkeyup = function () {
            if(this.value.length > 0) {
                var val_elm;
                for(var j = 0; j < _block.childNodes.length; j++) {
                    if(_block.childNodes[j].tagName == 'LI') {
                        val_elm = _block.childNodes[j].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                        _block.childNodes[j].style.display = (val_elm.indexOf(this.value.toLowerCase())  > -1 ? 'block' : 'none');
                    }
                }
                _block.style.display = 'block';
            } else _block.style.display = 'none';
        }                                       

        _inp[i].onfocus = function () {
            this.select();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

этот же скрипт переписал на jqury

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.auto-complete-prop-mft input:text').click(function () {
        $(this).select();
    });
    $('.auto-complete-prop-mft-block li').click(function () {
        $('.auto-complete-prop-mft input:text').val($(this).find('p').html());
        $('.auto-complete-prop-mft input:text').parent().find('span').html($(this).find('span').html());
        $('.auto-complete-prop-mft-block').hide();
    });

    $('.auto-complete-prop-mft input:text').on('keyup', function () {
        if($(this).val().length > 0) {
            $('.auto-complete-prop-mft-block li').each(function () {
                $(this).css('display', (
                    $(this).find('span').html().toLowerCase().indexOf($('.auto-complete-prop-mft input:text').val().toLowerCase()) > -1 ?
                    'block' : 'none'
                ));
            });
            $('.auto-complete-prop-mft-block').show();
        } else
            $('.auto-complete-prop-mft-block').hide();
    });
});
```

Теперь на событие keyup все очень долго происходит, в 5-10 раз медленнее чем на js. В чем проблема?

Хотя на js идет точно такой же перебор  элементов списка..

Comment: например потому, что на jquery не тот же самый код :-) сравните что происходит на keyup - в первом варианте и во втором. Ну и опять же все зависит от html и его размера и количества `li` например

Comment: Количество li и том и в этом случае одинаковое.

Почему разный код на keyup?

И там и там идет перебор всех li, и в зависимости от значения дочернего элемента ей выставляется display none или block

Comment: Я имел ввиду _общее_ количество. Да, запутался в одинаковых названиях. Каково количество инпутов в разметке?

Comment: `$('.auto-complete-prop-mft input:text').val()` совсем не то же самое что и `this.value.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Инпутов два-три..

Comment: пробовал так делать, `$('.auto-complete-prop-mft input:text').eq(0).val()`

Comment: а зачем вообще делать на jquery выборки, если вы тут нужен тот же `this.value`? Можете добавить в вопрос пример html на котором тестировали, и как замеряли скорость?

Comment: Использовал в административной части битрикса, скорость определял на глаз. 

При вводе в input вылезают сплывающие подсказки, на js мгновенно все выводится, а на jquery после введения каждого символа (на каждое событие keyup) приходится по 3-5 секунд ждать..

Comment: ну кроме того что в первом варианте используются _только_ первые элементы и выборки сохранены в переменные, а во втором выборки каждый раз и берутся все элементы которые найдены а не только первый особых различий нет. Нужно смотреть html

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/4169f9d16df45429e765add31fdf4589.png

На скришоте сплывающие подсказки - это сами элементы списка.

Вот сама структура hml: https://jsfiddle.net/88s6hdsm/

Единственное что я думаю, то это то что на jquery перебор элементов значительнее медленно работает.

Т.е. количество элементов li = 900

Comment: сколько элементов с этим классом? `auto-complete-prop-mft-block` вообще в разметке?

Comment: Всего один элемент с этим классом

Comment: и в нем 900 li?

Comment: да_____________

Comment: Вместо each написал for  $('.auto-complete-prop-mft-block li').eq(i) .. и стало чуть быстрее работать, но все равно не то что на чистом js

Comment: что-то не вижу особой разницы: https://jsfiddle.net/88s6hdsm/1/ даже с вариантом кода который в вопросе

Comment: Хммм... спасибо.

https://jsfiddle.net/88s6hdsm/2/

Добавил свои css стили что бы удобнее было работать.

Так же добавил свои 900-элементов li, значительных изменение не заметил.

5 раз вставил эти 900 li.

А теперь попробуйте проверить скорость))

А у меня на сайте их 900 только, но скорость такая же как и тут при 5 * 900

Comment: Особенно когда человек быстро печатает, чаще срабатывает keyup и еще сильнее тормозит.

Comment: Интересно из-за чего там медленно идет перебор у jquery))

Comment: а вот так? https://jsfiddle.net/88s6hdsm/4/ я бы не сказал что проблема в jQuery

Comment: спасибо))) хахах toLowerCase() так тупил что ли?)

Comment: нет, выборка более 4х тысяч элементов на каждое нажатие клавиши, заметь что в первом варианте, без jQuery Они не выбираются, а пробегаются сразу в цикле как childNodes

Comment: благодарю за помощь)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35781/discussion-on-question-by-ddddddddd-----jquery-).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что селекторы — тяжёлая функция. А вы ещё выбираете селекторы заново по нескольку раз. Вот пример, как надо бы исправлять (эта оптимизации уже проведена в скрипте, что вы исправили.

```
var tratata = $('.auto-complete-prop-mft-block li')
$('.auto-complete-prop-mft').keyup(function() {
    if (this.type == 'text') { // пока так выкрутимся, ок?
        if (this.value.length > 0) { // легко
            tratata.each(function () { // При проходе каждого prop-mft больше не обходим опять все prop-mft-block li
                $(this).css('display', ($(this).find('span').html().toLowerCase().indexOf($(this).find('input:text').val().toLowerCase()) > -1 ? 'block' : 'none')); // много селекторов, зачем?
            });
            $('.auto-complete-prop-mft-block').show(); // опять селекторы, зачем?
        } else {
            $('.auto-complete-prop-mft-block').hide(); // опять селекторы, зачем?
        }
    }
});
```